# How to fix Dual boot missing UEFI mode bootloader in window 8.1

Tags: linux, windows

My notebook exist UEFI mode windows 8.1 before install linux. When I install the sabayon-linux missing windows bootloader.
I tried the following solutions.But I can't.
How to fix boot repair windows 8.1 UEFI-bootloader?

1. [How to repair windows 8 efibootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)
2. [fix-uefi-boot](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/)
3. [Fix corrupt uefi partition](http://www.itechs-systems.com/fix_corrupt_UEFI_partition.aspx)

Pls help me.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

check this :
http://linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/

and try to use repair disk and active your partition
steps :
Enter **diskpart**, then list disk after diskpart is loaded.
Enter **select disk** [number of the disk the partition is on].
Enter **list partition**, followed by select partition [partition number]
Type active
then ,
**bootrec /fixmbr, /fixboot, /scanos, /rebuildbcd**

**Also You can re install your linux distro and accept to install the Grup loader.**

Comment: My notbook is Lenovo U4. I type the following code.
' DISKPART> list vol ' 
volume label are not display and all info are hidden type. I can't choose the boot volume.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all go to: https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html and
   follow the instruction to create a Repair  Disk.
2. Flow the instructions found here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
3. Then Go to your PC BIOS and delete all the file listed on BOOT----->EFI. Reboot you PC, And now you can see your option list with Ubuntu and Windows, make your choice and start using it.
4. If it does not work at first, do it again.